# Geofencing in React Native

Tags: react-native

At the time of this post I believe that there are no geofencing modules available for react native so I would like to implement an alternative poor man's strategy. I discovered react native's geolocation module however the official doc is not clear:

1) Does the Geolocation module run in the background and get the current user coordinates automatically (even if the app is in the background)? If yes, are these stored in a variable or a state?

2) If (1) is true, how can I detect a change in state? Because once I detect a change in state (i.e. user's location) I would like to push this new location to a remote server and store it in a database. On the other hand I do not want to store each and every inch the user is moving!

Does this strategy make sense at all? My concerns are battery consumption as well of course..

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to enable this feature in xcode [image: Settings] Then save the location you get from the 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition' callback somewhere in you app e.g. in your AsyncStorage

2) The callback is only getting called if the location is changed. So you don't need explicitly detect any location change.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5nvMQe-fpc